# Changing Discussion Folder Names in SharePoint 2010

Tags: discussion-board

Is there a way to change the name of a folder within the discussion area of SharePoint 2010? The folder by default is given the name of the discsussion name when it is created, however, if you then change the discussion name, it does not (quite rightly) automatically update the folder name - I would like to though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be doable with a Workflow as folders in a list are essentially ListItems.

If not, then write a EventReceiver to trigging when an item is updated, see if the discussion name was updated, then attempt to update the folder name.

I'm assuming uses Internal Names under the bonnet to reference discussions, so all you're really doing is updating display names.

Answer (score 0):

Open your site in explorer view and try to change.

Comment: I tried opening in Explorer to change title - it didn't work.